# meteor publish filter fields if other field exist

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection that two fields dependent on each other, and one of them can return to the client;
something like this,

```
    Books.find({},{
    fields:{
        user : function(){
            if(this.private == true){
                return 0
            }else{
                return 1
            }
        },
        private:1
    }
})
```

how can do that?

Comment: You should detail more your question. If disclosing the `user` field depend on the value of `private`, it is not how you should word it, nor exemplify it. Is that it?

Comment: yes, If disclosing the user field depend on the value of private.
this code just a sample to show what i want. @billybobbonnet